# How to find control in CommandItemTemplate for RadGrid

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I'm using RadGrid from Telerik with three LinkButton controls in CommandItem , and i want to hide or show them using switch statement at code behind.

```
<CommandItemTemplate>
   <LinkButton runat="server" ID="approveAllLink" Text="Approve All" >
   </LinkButton>
   <LinkButton runat="server" ID="approveLink" Text="Approve" >
   </LinkButton>
   <LinkButton runat="server" ID="rejectLink" Text="Reject" >
   </LinkButton>
</CommandItemTemplate>
```

Is there anyway solve this case?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What about this?

```
GridItem cmdItem = RadGrid1.MasterTableView.GetItems(GridItemType.CommandItem)[0]; 
LinkButton approveAllLink = cmdItem.FindControl("approveAllLink") as LinkButton; 
LinkButton approveLink = cmdItem.FindControl("approveLink") as LinkButton; 
LinkButton rejectLink= cmdItem.FindControl("rejectLink") as LinkButton; 

// Your switch logic here
```

Comment: I'm using version v2013.1.220.45 and this didn't work for me: the array is empty for the first line of the code above  - I'm using a custom `CommandItemTemplate` which might be the problem, not sure. My `CommandItemDisplay` settings is `TopAndBottom`.

Comment: @PeterX for sure in RadGrid1_ItemDataBound event the array is not null.

Comment: @PeterX try retrieving the controls in the `RadGrid_ItemCreated` handler using `FindControl()` on `GridCommandItem` as suggested in [this Telerik post](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet/grid/find-control-within-commanditemtemplate.aspx#668918)

Comment: The link from @BoyanK doesn't work anymore. Check it [this Telerik forum thread](http://www.telerik.com/forums/accessing-commanditemtemplate#lpXczk2kXU2dmp-E-XdpxA) for an example:

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have the CommandItemDisplay property of the MasterTableView set to a value different than None. Otherwise the command item array which is returned from the GetItems method will be empty.

Answer (score 2):

Hide or show the controls in your CommandItem during the grid's ItemCreated event:

```
    protected void RadGrid1_ItemCreated(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == GridItemType.CommandItem)
        {
            var approveAllLink = (LinkButton) e.Item.FindControl("approveAllLink");
            var approveLink = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("approveLink");
            var rejectLink = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("rejectLink");

            // Your switch logic here
        }
    }
```